# Create a weights adjacency matrix in python with networkX

Tags: networkx, dijkstra, osmnx

I want to implement the Dijkstra algorithm in python but with weighted adjacency matrix but NetworkX give us just the adjacency without the weights ( distance for my algorithm ) so I tried to search a way to create a weighted adjacency matrix but I didn't found. The only code I find from NetworkX is :

`A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G, weight='weight')`

This is my code for the rest :

`G = ox.graph_from_bbox(nord, sud, est, ouest, network_type='drive')`

`noeud_origine = ox.get_nearest_node(G, point_origine) noeud_destination = ox.get_nearest_node(G, point_destination)`

Comment: can you clarify your question? why are you not using `A` ?

Comment: @micro5 bc for dijkstra algorithm I need the weight of each edges to calculate the shortest path. The adjacency matrix gives me a matrix composed of 0 or 1 but not distances between each nodes

Comment: you can use [nx.shortest_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path) with weighted graphs. The default method is dijkstra.

Comment: @warped the fact is that I want to code the Dijkstra algorithm by my own